# How do information bars work, like the one appearing in stackoverflow when you win a badge?

Tags: jquery, html, css, notifications, toast

When you win a badge on SO, a bar with information appears on top. This looks to me like jQuery, but how is it actually implemented?

Comment: Just rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*?

Comment: The knee-jerk reaction would be to move this to meta, but I think it's a programming question, not a question about SO *per se*, isn't it?

Comment: @T.J. - I am inclined to give it the benefit of the doubt but I fear others will not.

Comment: This question should **not** be moved to Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: [GROWL](http://projects.zoulcreations.com/jquery/growl/)

If you code a fine, simple css you can easily make a stackoverflow lookalike without programming.

Answer (score 3):

I just used a div that's hidden and has a margin-top equal to the information bar's height until I want to trigger it. Then I just animate jQuery's show and animate() to change the margin-top to 0.
Alternately, you could just have it hidden and use slideDown(), but I prefer the animate() effect more.